# Comparing two tables and finding similar content in columns SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, compare, sql-like

Lets say I have two tables that contain similar objects, for example information about certain music albums. 
Table A has a very long list of albums that shows artists, album titles, release years and genres, but table B contains a shorter list of albums perhaps only by one artist (showing album titles, release years, genres).

Now I want to find what albums by the certain artist (shown in table B) are also shown in table A.

Usually I would probably do this by saying:

`select a.title
from tableA a, tableB b
where a.title = b.title`

But the problem is that table A and table B might show the titles in a different way, for example a title for an album in table A might be: "The Title" but the same album might be called: "The Title (feat. Artist2)" in table B. The differences might not always be the same however.

Is there any way of comparing these two tables and the title columns in those tables and finding albums that are in both tables, taking into consideration that the titles might differ even though they represent the same album?

The like function exists but is it possible to modify it to relate to these circumstances? Or might there be a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.title
FROM tableA a, tableB b
WHERE a.title LIKE '%' + b.title + '%'
```

Comment: I don't think this resolves the question well.  Doesn't this still require the string to have exactly `b.title` in it to match?  What if one is `'The Title'` and the other is `'ttl (ft. artist2)'`?  It should match, but it won't, in this case.